# how to "find" docs in mongodb (in python) where a substring exists in a field which is a list of strings?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have numerous mongodb documents which are like

veg_doc1 = {........,
     veg_name: [bean, beans, brown bean, red carrot,radish, ......],
     ......
}

veg_doc2 = {........,
      veg_name : [bean, black beans, cabbage, brown beans, gorbanzo bean, organic carrot, red carrots,.....],
      ..........
}

veg_doc3 = {...., 
      veg_name: [cabbage, beatroot, beans],
   ........
}

Can I design a query which picks up all documents that has "bean" & say "carrot" as elements in "veg_name" field (basically one or multiple items with an "and" operation") ? I should be able to pick all those where each element (in this case bean and carrot) is a substring in the name (should include say bean, black beans, beans, carrot, red carrots etc and also those who have  etc).

So if I query the above with ('bean', 'carrot') - I should get back both veg_doc1 and veg_doc2 but not veg_doc3.

Can someone help me here please?
(I am using python/pymongo)

I am doing this

veg_regex = '[*bean|*carrot]'
for sanc_doc in db.veg_collection.find({'vegetables':{'$in' {'$regex':veg_regex}}}):
    print(sanc_doc['vegetables'])

this doesn't work :-( Either I am doing something wrong in the regex or something wrong in the find query or may be both :-(

Comment: whatever is show as has answer, does not have an answer as they don't really talk about python/mongodb combo

Comment: Also the question is no duplicate since the other one is asking – at least the answers regard it that way – for *single* valued fields. Funny enough that the answers stay correct for multi-valued fields. Nevertheless: no duplicate.

Comment: Oh, another hint (just saw your update): Don't use a `re`. Just write the regular expression, like in `c.find({ "veg_name" : { "$regex" : "^carrot" } })`. Also no `$in` required. Yes, this **is** an independent question on it's own right. No duplicate at all.

Comment: I actually loved to dig into detail here. Please refer to this Gist for more insight into your issue: https://gist.github.com/flaschbier/a3e9419428fc0b47006a